# Python apply a func to two lists of lists, store the result in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

To simplify my problem, say I have two lists of lists and a function shown below:

```
OP = [[1,2,3],[6,2,7,4],[4,1],[8,2,6,3,1],[6,2,3,1,5], [3,1],[3,2,5,4]]
AP = [[2,4], [2,3,1]]

def f(listA, listB):
    return len(listA+listB) # my real f returns a number as well
```

I want to get the `f(OP[i],AP[j]) for each i, j`, so my idea is to create a `pandas.Dataframe` which looks like this:

```
            AP[0]          AP[1]
OP[0]   f(AP[0],OP[0])  f(AP[1],OP[0])
OP[1]   f(AP[0],OP[1])  f(AP[1],OP[1])
OP[2]   f(AP[0],OP[2])  f(AP[1],OP[2])
OP[3]   f(AP[0],OP[3])  f(AP[1],OP[3])
OP[4]   f(AP[0],OP[4])  f(AP[1],OP[4])
OP[5]   f(AP[0],OP[5])  f(AP[1],OP[5])
OP[6]   f(AP[0],OP[6])  f(AP[1],OP[6])
```

My real data actually has around 80,000 lists in OP and 20 lists in AP, and the function `f` is a little bit time consuming, so the computational cost should be worried.

My idea to achieve the goal would be constructing a `pandas.Series` of length `len(AP)`for each `OP`, and then append the `Series` to the final `Dataframe`. 
For example, for `OP[0]`, first create a `Series` which have all the information for `f(OP[0],AP[i]) for each i`.

I am stuck for constructing the `Series`. I tried `pandas.Series.apply()` and `map()`but neither or them worked since my function `f` needs two parameters.

I'm also open to any other suggestions to get `f(OP[i],AP[j]) for each i, j`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so with some nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), followed by an application of [`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/dsintro.html?highlight=from_records):

```
import pandas as pd

records = [tuple(f(A, O) for A in AP) for O in OP]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```